# Effects of Gravitational Potential on Acceleration From a non-local observer

Tags: general-relativity

For the following diagram:

[image]

Objects A and B are of equal mass, and are negligible compared to object M

At Time = 0, objects A and B are at rest with respect to M.

At Time > 0, both A and B exert equal amounts of thrust in the same direction for a finite amount of time.

My question is:
For a non-local observer, will both A and B appear to have accelerated equally in the opposing direction of thrust?  I'm not concerned with what acceleration results from the gravitational attraction from M.  I'm aware that the A will received more gravitational acceleration in the direction opposing thrust as A moves to the right, that isn't what I'm asking about.  I'm curious about the relativistic effects of from M and how they will impact the accelerations / velocities as a result of the difference between the two positions as marked A and B.

This question was inspired by shapiro time delay, if that provides some useful context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the proper acceleration is applied such that the resulting local velocity is the same, the particle B that is farther away from the mass will have a slower coordinate velocity as measured by the far away bookkeeper.

The easiest example is to make the proper acceleration so high that the local velocity approaches the speed of light, then the observed coordinate velocity is as in the Shapiro delay for photons, which is slower when the photon is closer to the mass.

If the motion is tangential the factor by which the observed velocity slows down is simply the factor for the gravitational time dilation, while for the radial component you also have to factor in the depth expansion.

Comment: Is paragraph #1 referring to tangential motion specifically?

Comment: Since you said *"I'm not concerned with what acceleration results from the gravitational attraction from M"* that is not really important, but like I said in paragraph 3, since gᵣᵣ=gᵗᵗ the factor by which the local vᵣ relative to stationary clocks and rulers differs from the observed dr/dt is 1-rₛ/r while for the tangential velocity it's only √(1-rₛ/r) since the tangential components of the metric tensor are euclidean, while the temporal and radial ones ain't, so tangentially you only have the time dilation, and radially the square of it (assuming Schwarzschild).